# Como bloquear a lista de sugestões de um input text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, input, text

Estou querendo bloquear aquela lista de sugestões que aparece quando digita alguma coisa num campo text, alguém sabe como faz?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os campos input possuem uma propriedade "autocomplete", você pode desativar para eliminar este comportamento

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
```

Mais informações:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: Obrigado @Bins, resolveu perfeitamente aqui.